# How was ‘only’ (‘onely’) pronounced in early modern English?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, early-modern-english

I have noticed in some older English literature, that ‘only’ is written ‘onely’. Was this merely an example of historical spelling, or does it reveal an earlier pronunciation not as modern /ˈəʊnlɪ/, but rather as /'wʌnlɪ/? An example:

> […] because it is upon a misinterpretable subject, I have always gone so near suppressing it, as that it is onely not burnt […]
> ―John Donne, in a letter of 1619 to Sir Robert Keer, as quoted in Al Alvarez: *The Savage God*, Weidenfeld and Nicolson, London, 1971, p. 133.

Later, in the same quote, the spelling is ‘only’, though I do not know whether this is a clerical error by Alvarez or whether Donne actually did use both spellings in the same letter. Given my (very minor) knowledge of 15th- to 17th-century English documents, and the same with Scandinavian and German documents, finding two different spellings of a word in the same document is not only plausible, but expected. Further, given what effort Alvarez has gone to to represent old texts correctly in his work, I assume it is in fact correct.

Earlier and later examples are presented by the OED:

> But the affeccion of the publique well may auoyde your singuler disordinate reule yf the voluntees ben conyoined all in oon onely desire to the comon saluacion.
> c1475   tr. A. Chartier Quadrilogue (Univ. Coll. Oxf.) (1974) 245 (MED)

> What cannot onely Sons with Parents do!
> OED: 1672   J. Dryden Conquest Granada ii. iii. ii. 109

> The power was retained; with this onely difference, that [etc.].
> OED: 1741   C. Middleton Hist. Life Cicero I. Pref. 35

> Onely, Onerly, lonely, retired. ‘This is an onely platt to live in’.
> OED: 1828   W. Carr Dial. Craven (ed. 2)

> Mon, aw’m one-ly when theaw artn’t theer.
> OED: 1856   E. Waugh in Manch. Weekly Examiner & Times 21 June (Suppl.) 3/3

However, the modern spelling ‘only’ is also listed as early as 1483:

> I that am an only sone to my fader and moder I shold depose theyr olde age with heuynes and sorow to helle.
> 1483   W. Caxton tr. J. de Voragine Golden Legende 77/3

In addition to this, you of course have other older spellings, like ‘anli’ and ‘oonly’. But the later usage of the spelling ‘only’ – ɔ: after the great vowel shift – I would presume would either represent (as per my question) either: a historical pronunciation or a representation of actual pronunciation. Hence my question: **How was only/onely pronounced in Early Modern English?** And further: **In Early Modern English, are we dealing with an historical spelling, or an actual representation of two competing pronunciations?**

Note: I may be mistaken in what I understand to be Modern English, so if there is a need for me to update my question (considering the original quote), please do advise me on this.

Comment: The first syllable of 'only' would probably have been [oːn-] in EModE (but I have nothing to back it up).

Comment: If it were not that we expect "one" to be pronounced as the number, "onely" would be a reasonable spelling of the 21st century pronunciation.

Comment: Another, related question would be how was "one" pronounced historically, given that the spelling of "one" strongly indicates a different pronunciation closer to modern "only".

Comment: @StuartF: 'One' was pronounced something like [oːn] until recently. The modern pronunciation of 'one' is a recent development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the people who spelled only as *onely* may have pronounced *one* without a /w/. The word *one* entered Middle English without a /w/, but by the 14th century (you can see this in the OED from the spellings ... see also [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=one)) some dialects were pronouncing it with a /w/; however, pronunciations without the /w/ lasted for several more centuries:

According to [Wordlady](https://katherinebarber.blogspot.com/2013/10/11-surprising-language-errors-that-have.html), in the blog post *11 surprising "language errors" that have become standard usage*,

> In 1685, Christopher Cooper, writing a grammar of English, described the pronunciation wun for ‘one’ as ‘barbarous speaking’.